# How to extend colors using a plugin in tailwindcss?

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, headless-cms

I would like to call an api to retrieve some colors and then extend the theme to include these colors.

```js
const plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin')
  
const getColors = async ()=>{
    // This function only returns one string to test
    let data = await fetch("api");
    data = await data.json();
    return data.story.content.color;
}

module.exports = plugin(function({ matchUtilities, theme }) {
  const color = await getColors(); // as an example it returns only one color - string format - not an array

  matchUtilities(
    {
      colors: (value) => ({
        color: value
      }),
    },
    { values: {primary: color}} // to access color as : text-primary/bg-primary
  )
})
```

This doesn't work. I can't seem to understand what matchUtilities does exactly and I can't think of a correct way.

I would like to get some help if possible. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

###### I can see two flaws in the code:

1. The matchUtilities function should be used with an array of color names, not just one color.
2. you can't use the `await` keyword inside the `module.exports` because there is no async function

---

###### Try to code something like:

```
const plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin');

const getColors = async () => {
    // This function retrieves some colors from an API
    let data = await fetch("api");
    data = await data.json();
    return data.story.content.color;
}

module.exports = plugin(async function({ matchUtilities, theme }) {
  const colorFromApi = await getColors();
  const colorsArray = colorFromApi.map(color => {
  return {
    [color]: color
   }
 })
  matchUtilities(
    {
     colors: (value) => colorsArray,
    },
    { values: {primary: color}}
  )
});
```

Comment: I get what you did, I tried it but it didn't work with some tweaking. What I don't understand is if I want to have the equivalent of `theme: {extend : {colors: {primary: "my-color"}}}`, what should goe into the values property in the second argument of matchutilities and what should this function return its first argument.